# Getting an access token without a browser

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-access-token

To give you some background information, I am currently working a backend to an application that keeps count of Facebook notifications on a very small 32-character LCD screen, hooked up to an [Arduino](http://arduino.cc). To do this, I have opened a Facebook application, and have a page on my server that redirects a user for authorization and permissions, and then proceeds to fetch an access token. In my browser, all the redirects work perfectly, and I end up with a JSON representation of my notifications. However, I would like this to work autonomously - when I try to fetch the page with Ruby, to parse the results and write them to the serial port, the result is the javascript used to redirect the user to the Facebook dialog, and not the notifications. I.E. client-side code is returned, not executed (not surprisingly).

My question is whether there is anyway to obtain authorization, and request an access token without redirecting to another page, or running code client-side?

Answer (score 0):

How do you fetch this page "using Ruby" because if you will get redirect you can check requests status code and if it is 302 read location and perform redirect reading location url.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/

Another way is to "pregenerate" an AccessToken and simply use it hardcoded or as an inputform or whatever you prefer. This way you don't have to take the roundtrip to your server.